# memory ordering rules - What do I missed here:

Tags: c++, atomic, shared-ptr

In my opinion, the following is UB, and therefore similar situations with a shared_ptr also. Do I have overseen something of the memory ordering rules?

```
struct InternalCnt{
    
    
    void ref();
    void release();
    void doX(); // irrelevant, but no visible side-effects.

    std::atomic<int> cnt{1};
};

void InternalCnt::ref(){cnt.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order::relaxed);}
void InternalCnt::release(){
   if(cnt.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order_acq_rel) == 1){
       delete this;
   }
}

std::atomic<InternalCnt*> shared_data{};

void t1(){
    auto* my_data = new InternalCnt;
    my_data.ref();
    shared_data.store(my_data, std::memory_order::relaxed);
    my_data.reset();
}

void t2(){
    while(!send.load(std::memory_order::relaxed));
    shared_data->doX()
    shared_data->release();
}
```

My assumption:

```
1 t1: my_data.cnt == 1
2 t1: my_data.ref::cnt.atomic::fetch_add(1, std::memory_order_relaxed); 
3 t1: shared_data->store(my_data, std::memory_order::relaxed);
4 t2: shared_data->load(my_data, std::memory_order::relaxed) != 0;
5 t2: shared_data->release();
6 t1: my_data->release();

1 is sequenced before 2 and 3;
2 is unknown sequenced to 3 and vice versa ( 2 <\-> 3)
3 Inter-thread happens-before 4, since 4 synchronizes-with 3
2 is sequenced before 6
4 is sequenced before 5
```

This allows the following visual effects: |t1:1->3|->|(t2):4->5|->|t1:2->6|

Which results in a cnt of 0 in t2 and a double deletion in (6) => UB

The same should happen in such an situation:

```
static std::shared_ptr<X> shared_data;
static std::atomic<bool> send{};


void t1(){
    std::shared_ptr<X> my_data;
    shared_data = my_data;
    send.store(true, std::memory_order::relaxed);
    my_data.reset();
}

void t2(){
    while(!send.load(std::memory_order::relaxed));
    shared_data.reset();
}
```

Comment: Your atomic operations on the ```send``` and ```shared_data``` variable need acquire and release. You seem to know this. So what is your question, specifically?

Comment: Only, if my assumption is right. We have a c++ mixed C project, where we can't use shared_ptr. And my concern was, that this could result in UB. On the other hand, noone would share data without release-aquire semantics.

Comment: Yes, your assumption that the code above is broken is correct. You need acquire and release on the global variables. It doesn't matter what atomics you use. C or C++. Your reference counter seems correct. It only gets complicated once you introduce weak pointers. Does that answer your question?

Comment: Yes, thanks, you can add this comment as solution.

Comment: A couple problems with your analysis:  First, 2 is actually sequenced before 3.  "Sequencing" is normal program order within a single thread, and 2 and 3 are separate full expressions in separate statements of the same thread.  Second and more importantly, **4 does not synchronize with 3**.  It would if they were release and acquire per atomics.order p2, but there is no such promise for relaxed loads and stores; that is kind of the whole point of relaxed.

Comment: Thanks for the refresher, read the paragraphs again.